# Local resource file content not showing over Internet Explorer but fine on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, multilingual, resource-files

My web app is multilingual...I have used Local resource files for multilingual changes....The content are picking up correctly over Chrome & Firefox but not on Internet Explorer...I am not getting why is this happening...Please help......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found answer for this....the default browser of computer uses your local computer language & cultural..i have enables it and it worked like a charm...thanks